# JS string.split() without removing the delimiters

Tags: javascript, split, delimiter

How can I split a string without removing the delimiters?

Let's say I have a string:
`var string = "abcdeabcde";`

When I do
`var newstring = string.split("d")`, I get something like this:

`["abc","eabc","e"]`

But I want to get this:

`["abc","d","eabc","d","e"]`

When I tried to do my "split2" function, I got all entangled in splice() and indexes and "this" vs "that" and ... aargh! Help! :D

Comment: @ruffin It's not marked but has the same comment pointing back here. They are both *suggested* as duplicates of each other - we should somehow make up our minds which one to close :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try this:

1. Replace all of the "d" instances into ",d"
2. Split by ","

```
var string = "abcdeabcde";
var newstringreplaced = string.replace(/d/gi, ",d");
var newstring = newstringreplaced.split(",");
return newstring;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: fastest answer according to firebugs profiler

Comment: Your solution has one mistake - it works when I replace the instances not with ",d", but with ",d,". Nice idea! Accepting because of the simplicity :)

Comment: "abcdeabcde".split(/(d)/);

Comment: Fails for any `,` in the original string.

Comment: bobince, yes, I guess it's not safe if the original string contains ',' somewhere. But I like principle.

Comment: How would you do this if your split regex had more than one delimniator? eg `/[abc]/`

Comment: @dwjohnston
This is the wrong answer... You are supposed to use capturing parenthesis like in Kai's answer.

Comment: this adds empty strings to the array if there are adjacent occurrences of the target char. `abcdda => [abc, d, '', d, a]`, is there a way to remove those (elegantly, without performing a 2nd loop)?

Answer (score 87):

Try:

```
"abcdeabcde".split(/(d)/);
```

Comment: Note this doesn't work in IE due to JScript bugs.

Comment: OP didn't specify if the environment was a browser or not

Comment: Which IE doesn't work?

Comment: These are capturing parenthesis. They are the correct way to keep (part of) the separator strings in the returned array as odd entries.

Comment: What if I want the result to be ["abc", "deabc", "de"] ? like having the splict character joined with the next split?

Comment: @MikeAono: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45323715/859877, by using regex `/(?=d)/g`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer: it's simpler and safer, and IE is rarely a requirement lately

Answer (score 45):

I like [Kai's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4514223/1974224), but it's incomplete. Instead use:

```
"abcdeabcde".split(/(?=d)/g) //-> ["abc", "deabc", "de"]
```

This is using a [Lookahead Zero-Length Assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in regex, which makes a match not part of the capture group. No other tricks or workarounds needed.

Comment: Is there a solution to get this result : //-> ["abcd", "eabcd", "e"]

Comment: @forresst Not with a single split command, AFAIK.  But the accepted answer oddly enough does almost that, except with leading delimiters in stead of trailing.

Comment: @forresst @JoachimLous You can just use a lookbehind approach, which is also described on the page linked by micha. E.g.: `"abcdeabcde".split(/(?<=d)/g)`

Answer (score 21):

```
var parts= string.split('d');
for (var i= parts.length; i-->1;)
    parts.splice(i, 0, 'd');
```

(The reversed loop is necessary to avoid adding `d`s to parts of the list that have already had `d`s inserted.)

Comment: +1 much safer than accepted answer.

Comment: plus one for using ```-->``` operator :D

Comment: [What is the name of the “-->” operator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1642028/1529630)

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer, better than regexing or replacing with a special character that might naturally occur

Comment: Seeing this answer, I'm once again happy to use [prettier](https://prettier.io/) … 
+1 for the functionality though!

Answer (score 5):

split - split is used to create separate lines not for searching.

[^d] - find a group of substrings not containing "d"

```
var str = "abcdeabcde";

str.match(/[^d]+|d/g)         // ["abc", "d", "eabc", "d", "e"]
or
str.match(/[^d]+/g)           // ["abc", "eabc", "e"]
or
str.match(/[^d]*/g)           // ["abc", "", "eabc", "", "e", ""]
```

Read "RegExp Object" if you do not want problems with the "javascript".

Comment: No problem. I've tried make it a little clearer. Please feel free to rollback or edit if I've made a mistake.

Comment: Global objects change affects the speed.
Methods "RegExp" - versatile and quick.
If the code is large, it is easier to understand the code.
This is my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

This is my version for regexp delimiters. It has same interface with String.prototype.split; it will treat global and non global regexp with no difference. Returned value is an array that odd member of it are matched delimiters.

```
function split(text, regex) {
    var token, index, result = [];
    while (text !== '') {
        regex.lastIndex = 0;
        token = regex.exec(text);
        if (token === null) {
            break;
        }
        index = token.index;
        if (token[0].length === 0) {
            index = 1;
        }
        result.push(text.substr(0, index));
        result.push(token[0]);
        index = index + token[0].length;
        text = text.slice(index);
    }
    result.push(text);
    return result;
}

// Tests
assertEquals(split("abcdeabcde", /d/), ["abc", "d", "eabc", "d", "e"]);
assertEquals(split("abcdeabcde", /d/g), ["abc", "d", "eabc", "d", "e"]);
assertEquals(split("1.2,3...4,5", /[,\.]/), ["1", ".", "2", ",", "3", ".", "", ".", "", ".", "4", ",", "5"]);
assertEquals(split("1.2,3...4,5", /[,\.]+/), ["1", ".", "2", ",", "3", "...", "4", ",", "5"]);
assertEquals(split("1.2,3...4,5", /[,\.]*/), ["1", "", "", ".", "2", "", "", ",", "3", "", "", "...", "4", "", "", ",", "5", "", ""]);
assertEquals(split("1.2,3...4,5", /[,\.]/g), ["1", ".", "2", ",", "3", ".", "", ".", "", ".", "4", ",", "5"]);
assertEquals(split("1.2,3...4,5", /[,\.]+/g), ["1", ".", "2", ",", "3", "...", "4", ",", "5"]);
assertEquals(split("1.2,3...4,5", /[,\.]*/g), ["1", "", "", ".", "2", "", "", ",", "3", "", "", "...", "4", "", "", ",", "5", "", ""]);
assertEquals(split("1.2,3...4,5.", /[,\.]/), ["1", ".", "2", ",", "3", ".", "", ".", "", ".", "4", ",", "5", ".", ""]);
assertEquals(split("1.2,3...4,5.", /[,\.]+/), ["1", ".", "2", ",", "3", "...", "4", ",", "5", ".", ""]);
assertEquals(split("1.2,3...4,5.", /[,\.]*/), ["1", "", "", ".", "2", "", "", ",", "3", "", "", "...", "4", "", "", ",", "5", "", "", ".", ""]);
assertEquals(split("1.2,3...4,5.", /[,\.]/g), ["1", ".", "2", ",", "3", ".", "", ".", "", ".", "4", ",", "5", ".", ""]);
assertEquals(split("1.2,3...4,5.", /[,\.]+/g), ["1", ".", "2", ",", "3", "...", "4", ",", "5", ".", ""]);
assertEquals(split("1.2,3...4,5.", /[,\.]*/g), ["1", "", "", ".", "2", "", "", ",", "3", "", "", "...", "4", "", "", ",", "5", "", "", ".", ""]);

// quick and dirty assert check
function assertEquals(actual, expected) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(actual) === JSON.stringify(expected));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var string = "abcdeabcde";
    var delim = "d";
    var newstring = string.split(delim);
    var newArr = [];
    var len=newstring.length;
    for(i=0; i<len;i++)
    {
        newArr.push(newstring[i]);
        if(i != len-1)newArr.push(delim);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function split2(original){
   var delimiter = "d", result = [], tmp;
   tmp = original.split(delimiter);
   tmp.forEach(function(x){result.push(x); result.push(delimiter); });
   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"abcdeabcde".split("d").reduce((result, value, index) => {
    return (index !== 0) ? result.concat(["d", value]) : result.concat(value)
}, [])
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var string = "abcdeabcde";
var res = string.replace( /d/g, 'd\0' ).split(/(?=d)|\0/);
console.log( res );
//["abc", "d", "eabc", "d", "e"]
```