# javascript regexp split including delimiter

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to split `'9088{2}12{1}729'` into `[ "9088", "{2}12", "{1}729" ]`

or even more useful to me: `[ "9088", "2-12", "1-729" ]`

tried:

```
'9088{2}12{1}729'.split(/\{[0-9]+\}/); => ["9088", "12", "729"]
```

also tried:

```
'9088{2}12{1}729'.match(/\{[0-9]+\}/); => ["{2}"]
```

I know it probably involved some other regexp string to split including delimiters.

---

Tried it in php, I guess you can do it in one line also.

```
preg_split( '/{/', preg_replace( '/}/', '-', "9088{2}12{1}729" ) )

Array ( [0] => 9088 [1] => 2-12 [2] => 1-729 )
```

Just have to wrap the replace function with split to get the preference order correct.

I think I like js more :)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514144/js-string-split-without-removing-the-delimiters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> even more useful to me: [ "9088", "2-12", "1-729" ]

It can be done using simple tricks!

```
"9088{2}12{1}729".replace(/\}/g,'-').split(/\{/g)

// ["9088", "2-12", "1-729"]
```

Comment: Do you have a bottle of awesomeness by your desk :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple zero-width [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) with `/(?={)/`:

```
'9088{2}12{1}729'.split(/(?=\{)/);  // => ["9088","{2}12","{1}729"]
```

The "zero-width" part means that the actual matched text is the empty string so the split throws away nothing, and the lookahead means it matches just before the contained pattern, so `/(?=\{)/` matches the empty strings between characters where indicated by an arrow:

```
9 0 8 8 { 2 } 1 2 { 1 } 7 2 9
       ↑         ↑
```

You can then use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to convert from `{1}2` form to `1-2` form.

```
'9088{2}12{1}729'.split(/(?=\{)/)
    .map(function (x) { return x.replace('{', '').replace('}', '-'); });
```

yields

```
["9088","2-12","1-729"]
```