# JavaScript split lookbehind

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to split a string by `\.\s` but leave the `.` appended to the array element.

Taking this string as a test, `Lorem Ipusm. Excepteur sint occaecat.` I need the output array to be:

```
[0] => Lorem Ipsum.
[1] => Excepteur sint occaecat.
```

See how the `.` still remains intact?

I believe I need a lookbehind regex because `/\.(?=\s)*/` doesn't work, instead the `.` ends up at the beginning of each sentence after it.

Comment: Are you looking for this? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514144/js-string-split-without-removing-the-delimiters

Comment: Yeah I did, but I got an invalid capture group, or something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript and regex: split string and keep the separator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001953/javascript-and-regex-split-string-and-keep-the-separator)

Comment: @TillHelge, JavaScript does not support Lookbehind assertions.

Comment: @stema Yeah...I just messed around with a jsfiddle and realized that by now. Never needed that before. Thanks for confiming my suspicion. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
var s = "Lorem Ipsum. Excepteur sint occaecat.",
    parts = s.match(/(.+?\.(?:\s|$))/g); 
    // ["Lorem Ipsum. ", "Excepteur sint occaecat."]
```

Comment: Note the space at the end of the first result in array - but it is easy to take care of, though.