# JavaScript break sentence by words

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's a good strategy to get full words into an array with its succeeding character.

Example.

> This is an amazing sentence.

```
Array(
[0] => This 
[1] => is
[2] => an
[3] => amazing
[4] => sentence.
)
```

Elements 0 - 3 would have a succeeding space, as a period succeeds the 4th element.

I need you to split these by spacing character,
Then once width of element with injected array elements reaches X,
Break into a new line.

Please, gawd don't give tons of code. I prefer to write my own just tell me how you would do it.

Comment: Use the javascript [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function.

Comment: I'd take the approach provided in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514144/js-string-split-without-removing-the-delimiters. But for your case change the `var newstringreplaced = string.replace(/d/gi, ",d");` to `var newstringreplaced = string.replace(/\s/gi, " ,");`. **Edit:** Should be advised this approach is only useful if your original string doesn't have a `,`. I suppose this solution is much safer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4514241/1417588

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Just use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
var str = "This is an amazing sentence.";
var words = str.split(" ");
console.log(words);
//["This", "is", "an", "amazing", "sentence."]
```

and if you need it with a space, why don't you just do that? (use a loop afterwards)

```
var str = "This is an amazing sentence.";
var words = str.split(" ");
for (var i = 0; i < words.length - 1; i++) {
    words[i] += " ";
}
console.log(words);
//["This ", "is ", "an ", "amazing ", "sentence."]
```

*Oh, and sleep well!*

Comment: @cars10 Changed the answer - does this fix it?

Comment: @cars10 why would you need the blanks at the end of each word? If you want them back when you concat your string just `.join(' ');`

Comment: I was just typing this up. Good, quick response.

Comment: Good answer :) i need the spaces because the users sentence has spaces and i plan to re output their sentence without having to declare a space in the loop. :) THANK U

Comment: @user2716649 As Dennis Martinez mentioned, you can simply use [`words.join(" ")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to get `This is an amazing sentence.` again.

Comment: how about multiple spaces between words!? ... it will put empty string elements inside array ... "asd asd  asd 00 0".split(' ').filter(Boolean) solves that

Comment: @user2846569 You can just use regex - `string.split(/\s+/g)`

Comment: @h2ooooooo nope ... check " a b b ".split(/\s+/g) ... ["", "a", "b", "b", ""]

Comment: @user2846569 `' a b b '.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').split(/\s+/g);`

Comment: and don't forget `map`. If you did need to add spaces to each word, then `map` is your friend.

Answer (score 78):

Similar to [Ravi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18473642/291280), use `match`, but use the word boundary `\b` in the regex to split on word boundaries:

```
'This is  a test.  This is only a test.'.match(/\b(\w+)\b/g)
```

yields

```
["This", "is", "a", "test", "This", "is", "only", "a", "test"]
```

or

```
'This is  a test.  This is only a test.'.match(/\b(\w+\W+)/g)
```

yields

```
["This ", "is  ", "a ", "test.  ", "This ", "is ", "only ", "a ", "test."]
```

Comment: This is indeed the best answer, as split by space is not really usable for real-life scenarios. Well, unless you don't use punctuation and always use single whitespace.

Comment: That converts "won't" into "won" and "t". This allows contractions: str.match(/\b(\w+)'?(\w+)?\b/g)

Comment: english words only :(

Comment: \b does not work with non ASCII chars. For example 'é'.match(/\b(\w+)\b/g) returns null

Comment: @Clement Something like `/(\p{L}+\P{L}+)/` might work with ES2018 (or PCRE), but it's unclear to me whether there's any real support for that.  Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48902765/291280

Answer (score 20):

try this

```
var words = str.replace(/([ .,;]+)/g,'$1§sep§').split('§sep§');
```

This will

1. insert a marker `§sep§` after every chosen delimiter `[ .,;]+`
2. split the string at the marked positions, thereby preserving the actual delimiters.

Answer (score 9):

If you need spaces and the dots the easiest would be.

```
"This is an amazing sentence.".match(/.*?[\.\s]+?/g);
```

the result would be

```
['This ','is ','an ','amazing ','sentence.']
```

Answer (score 8):

Use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove leading and trailing whitespaces.

```js
let str = '     This is an amazing sentence.  ',
  words = str.split(' ').filter(w => w !== '');

console.log(words);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option if you wanted to include the space and complete in O(N)

```
var str = "This is an amazing sentence.";
var words = [];
var buf = "";
for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    buf += str[i];
    if(str[i] == " ") {
        words.push(buf);
        buf = "";
    }
}

if(buf.length > 0) {
    words.push(buf);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The following solution splits words, not only by space, but also other types of spaces and punctuation characters. In addition, it works with non ASCII characters.

It matches words by considering only characters that belong to certain [categories of characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#General_Category). It allows letters (L), numbers (N), symbols (S) and marks (M) so it matches quite a broad set but you can adjust if you need a different set of characters. Other categories such as punctuations (P) and separators (Z) are not included and will therefore not match.

```
input.match(/[\p{L}\p{N}\p{S}\p{M}]+/gu)
```

Example

```
' \t a 件数  ,;-asd'.match(/[\p{L}\p{N}\p{S}\p{M}]+/gu)
```

Returns `['a', '件数', '', 'asd']`

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with lodash [`_.words`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#words):

```js
var str = 'This is an amazing sentence.';
console.log(_.words(str, /[^, ]+/g));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with `split` function:

```
"This is an amazing sentence.".split(' ')
```