# How to change a phrase string into an array of word string in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to change a phrase string into an array of word string in angularjs. For example i would like to transform `$scope.phrase='come back home'` to  `$scope.words=['come','back','home']`

Can you please help

Comment: duplicate  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473326/javascript-break-sentence-by-words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method.

`Split` method splits a String object into an array of strings.

```
$scope.words=$scope.phrase.split(' ');
```

Here is a working [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/12854/).

Answer (score 1):

Use [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) string method:

`$scope.words = $scope.phrase.split(' '); // Using space as param`