# Javascript : Create a variable that returns me only the first word of page title

Tags: javascript, variables, title

I have a website page with a three words title. 
how can I create a variable in Javascript that outputs only the first word of that title ?

thanks for your help !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript break sentence by words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473326/javascript-break-sentence-by-words)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of way to do that. If you have these words separated by space, the simplest and straightforward you can write the following:

```
const firstWord = pageTitle.split(' ')[0];
```

If you need to extract page title from browser API, just address `document.title` and use it as `pageTitle` variable.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const firstWord = document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerText.split(' ')[0]
```

**Description:**

`docuemnt.getElementsByTagName('tagName')` finds all the elements with the given tagName. We want only only the first element of it. Hence add put `[0]` next to it.

`innerText` gives the content of the given element.

`split(" ")` splits the given string into an array based on the argument. Here since we want to split into words, we use empty space `' '`. Since we need only the first word, you have to again use `[0]`

Comment: Sometimes page titles have extra spacing... I would be safe and just use: `document.title.trim().split(/\s+/).shift()` (no need for global pattern).

Answer (score 0):

If you need the first "word" of the title, you can:

1. Access the `document.title`
2. Trim any unnecessary white-space
3. Shift the resulting array to grab the first sequence of non-white-space characters

**Note:** You do not need to use the global flag for the expression, because we only care about the left-hand side of the split.

```js
const firstWordOfTitle = document.title.trim().split(/\s+/).shift();

console.log(`First word of document: "${firstWordOfTitle}"`); // "Test"
```

```html
<title>Test Title</title>
```