# Trying to return the longest word but eliminating a certain character

Tags: javascript

My desired result is `sentence` but it returns `sentence.`. How do I specify that I want to eliminate the '.'?

```js
function longestWord(string) {
  var str = string.split(" ");
  var longest = 0;
  var word = null;
  var sep = '.,?!';
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (sep.includes(str[i])) {
      str[i] = str[i].substring(0, str[i].length - 1);
    }
    if (longest < str[i].length) {
      longest = str[i].length;
      word = str[i];
    }
  }
  return word;
}

console.log(longestWord('Create a function to return the longest word(s) in a sentence.'));
```

Comment: `sep.includes(str[i])` checks if the string `'.,?!'` has the full word `str[i]` in it. Instead of using `split`, you can simply use `var str = string.match(/\b(\w+)\b/g)` to directly get the words. This will remove the comma, dots etc. Then you woudn't need the `sep` logic at all: [JavaScript break sentence by words](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36508315)

Comment: On your example you have two words that satisfy your criteria - they're the longest ones with the same length - 8 chars. *function* and *sentence*. What would be the expected result? *Sentence.* isn't really a word. It's a word followed by punctuation.

Comment: In your example you have `word(s)`; how should it be considered? Should it be classified as a 4, 5 or 7 characters word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your include condition doesn't work as expected.

```js
function longestWord(string) {
  var str = string.split(" ");
  var longest = 0;
  var word = null;
  var sep = '.,?!';
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i].split('').some(v => sep.split('').includes(v))) {
      str[i] = str[i].substring(0, str[i].length - 1);
    }
    if (longest <= str[i].length) {
      longest = str[i].length;
      word = str[i];
    }
  }
  return word;
}

console.log(longestWord('Create a function to return the longest word(s) in a sentence.'));
```

"function" and "sentence" is have same length.
so, i changed equal condition of second if statement.

Answer (score 4):

Regex would work better

```js
const nonAlpha = /[^\w\s]|_/g  // non alphabetic and underscore

const longestWord = string => string
   .replace(nonAlpha,"").split(" ")    // remove non alphabetics    
   .sort((a,b) => a.length - b.length) // sort on length
   .pop();                             // return the longest


console.log(longestWord('Create a function to return the longest word(s) in a sentence.'));
```

Answer (score 3):

**Tweaks at your existing solution**

You could use replace by regex to exclude `sep`

Moreover, the `if (longest < str[i].length) {` should also be changed to `<=` so you will have the latest longest word, because `function` also is the same lenghth as `sentence`

```js
function longestWord(string) {
  var str = string.split(" ");
  var longest = 0;
  var word = null;
  var sep = ".,?!";
  var regex = new RegExp(`[${sep}]`, "g");
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    str[i] = str[i].replace(regex, "");
    if (longest <= str[i].length) {
      longest = str[i].length;
      word = str[i];
    }
  }
  return word;
}

console.log(
  longestWord("Create a function to return the longest word(s) in a sentence.")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using .replace

for example:

```
var str = "sentence."

str = str.replace(".", "")
```

same .replace logic can be used to loop through the input string and potentially add other characters such as /,; etc.