# Is there an easy way to return all words from string?

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a way to return all words in a given string? The best solution I have currently found is using the match method and returning any string with at least one non-whitespace char (/\S+/g).

The issue with this method is that it includes a comma, period, etc. in the word. If I try using a RegExp with \w, then it doesn't include periods and commas, but it makes "don't" two words because of the '.

Is there any true and easy solution to this issue?

For example: "I don't want to go, mom". This should return the words [I, don't, want, to, go, mom]

Comment: What sorts of words including commas would you want to include, that wouldn't count as two separate words instead? I suppose for periods you're thinking of abbreviations like `U.S.` or something like that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript break sentence by words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473326/javascript-break-sentence-by-words)

Comment: @AlexanderHemming No. All the solutions have flaws I spoke about in my post.

Comment: Generally, you'll need to first list, how you want to treat all the edge cases. The issue with this is, that you just say "do it right", but probably didn't consider a lot of rather difficult edge-cases. Speaking of those, "edge-cases" includes a hyphen. Are those two words? One?

Comment: Please elaborate on what sorts of words with commas you want to permit. I don't think there's a good way to separate out words that end with a `.` from words that are at the end of a sentence, eg `Dr.`

Comment: What is the problem with separating by only the spaces with he split method?

it will not make "don't" "don" + "'t"

Comment: @AlexanderHemming It will count spaces as a word if you have newlines etc.

Comment: I once did something like this, not remembering all steps. I first replaced all `,` with space, then replaced all "period followed by space" `. `  After that used `str.split(" ")` to get the words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use word boundaries in regex and `match` function

```js
const matches = "I don't want to go, mom.".match(/(\b[^\s]+\b)/g);

console.log(matches);
```

Comment: This is something I was looking for! Thank you! @Vishundev

Comment: This will not match words that end in periods or apostrophes

Comment: @CertainPerformance I just tested it and it does? Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, it does. @CertainPerformance Can you give an example?

Comment: "A lot of suburbs' houses are large" - where did the apostrophe go? PS: I am unsure, what the intended solution is, but i was already in the comments above, so maybe it is exactly, what OP wanted.

Comment: It doesn't match `Dr.`, but `Dr`. It also doesn't match the apostrophe in `Employees' records`

Comment: @ASDFGerte That is true. For my task, this does exactly what it needs to though so I'm happy. It is also the best start if you want to add those functionalities too, from what I've seen so far.

Answer (score 4):

Would this work?

```
mystr.replace(".","").split(/\s/g);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using just the example string you've provided this worked:

```js
myString = "I don't want to go, mom"
wordsArray = []
myString = myString.replace(',', '')
wordsArray = myString.split(' ')
console.log({wordsArray})
```

But be ware that you have so much additional cases:

"two-handed" there is one or two words? `['two', 'handed']`, `['two-handed']` or `['twohanded']`

"Mrs. Foo", "Dr. bar"... expecting: `['Mrs', 'Foo'], ['Mrs. Foo'], ['Mrs.Foo'], ['MrsFoo']` ?