# How can I convert each of the words in a string to each be an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Is there a way to convert each word of a string to each have an array? For example, say I have the variable below.

`Let str = "Just typing out some words";`
I would like to convert this to what I have below

`Let arrs = [[Just], [typing], [out], [some], [words]]`

Is there any way that I can achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. *(not my downvote)*

Comment: Yes it is possible. Share what you tried for better response.

Comment: There certainly ways to achieve this, but kindly, show us what you have done so far to solve your issue.

Comment: [JavaScript break sentence by words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473326/javascript-break-sentence-by-words) + `.map()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const str = "Just typing out some words";
const arr = str.split(' ').map((node) => [node]);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: @Aj4short You are welcome. Please approve the answer if this solved your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This would do the job.

```
str.split(" ").map((s) => [s])
```