# target ever second word in a string using map function

Tags: javascript, arrays, map-function

Apply the map() function to the variable `str` so that every second word in the string is converted to uppercase. in javascript.

```
str = "hello my name is jon and i live in. canada."
```

Comment: SO what did you attempt?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473326/javascript-break-sentence-by-words

Comment: Use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to get the words, and then utilize the second parameter of [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (*the index of the word*) to identify if it is an even word that needs capitalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
"hello my name is jon and i live in. canada."
    .split(" ")
    .map((word, idx) => idx % 2 === 0 ? word : word.toUpperCase())
    .join(" ")
```

The trick is:

1. Split by spaces.
2. Map with index, but only use `toUpperCase()` if `idx % 2 !== 0`.
3. Then `join` back with spaces.