# How can I split a string into tokens in Javascript, including the white spaces?

Tags: javascript, regex

For example, the following string: `"  Hello  Wor$LD !! "` should be converted to :

```
["  ","Hello","  ","Wor$LD"," ","!!"," "]
```

I tried to split the string using \b , but it fails when there are non-word characters, such as $ and !.

Note that all white spaced should be grouped together.

Comment: at face value it looks like you just want to `string.split(' ')` or I guess maybe `string.split(/(\s+)/)`

Comment: Thanks, but this does not give the expected result. The white spaces need to be preserved.

Comment: `str.replace(/\s/g, ' ☺').split('☺')`

Comment: wrap in capture group `string.split(/(\s+)/)`

Comment: @karthikmanchala Note the other question doesn't want to group whitespaces. But they are still almost duplicates, not sure if it should be closed.

Comment: @Oriol the difference between the two questions is trivial

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match the groups which either only contain whitespaces or don't contain any.

```js
"  Hello  Wor$LD !! ".match(/\s+|\S+/g);
```

Note that if the string is empty, it will return `null`. If you want an empty array, add `|| []` at the end.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503827/split-string-into-array-without-deleting-delimiter