# Make <br /> from string works in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here are some ajax calls returns `<br />` in their data, while I found it was hard to handle.

Here is what I got for now, but not working at all. The string was split correctly, while react gave me several `<span></span>` tags without proper `<br />` line breaks.

```js
const breakLine = text => {
    const regex = /<br\s*[\/]?>/gi

    return text.split(regex).map(
        line => line.match(regex) ? React.createElement('br') : line
    )
}

const Text = ({ content }) => <p>
    { breakLine(content) }
<p>

// Usage
<Text content="Here are some <br /> Lines <br> to break!" />
```

Comment: There is now a far better way to do this in modern versions of React. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36377593/2237142

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you split using the regex your array will not contain the `<br />` tags as split removes the delimiter.

```
let splitText = text.split(regext);
// ["Here are some ", " Lines ", " to break!"]
```

Which makes your ternary always hit the false clause and only return the actual line.

One way of doing it can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514144/js-string-split-without-removing-the-delimiters)

Working example regex courtesy of @JonMayer

```
function breakLine(text) {
    var br = React.createElement('br');
    var regex = /(<br \/>)/g;
    return text.split(regex).map(function(line, index) {
        return line.match(regex) ? <br key={"key_" + index} /> : line;
    });
}

var Text = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>{ breakLine(this.props.content) }</div>;
    }
});

React.render(<Text content="Here are some <br /> Lines <br /> to break!" />, document.body);
```

Comment: Oh, my... I was testing with `\n`, find it works so I didn't aware of the strange regex behaviour. You are awesome dude!

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely looking for dangerouslySetInnerHTML.  The following code will work without needing the breakLine function.

```
const Text =  ({content}) => {
    return (
       <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: content}}></p>
    );
};
```

Comment: No body should go out looking for danger...ouslySetInnerHTML :)