# How to use whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap' on React

Tags: css, whitespace, reactjs, jsx

How can I use the style whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap' on React

I have a div that need to render the text using the format with spaces

```
render() {
   <div style={{whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap'}}
      keep formatting

      keep spaces
   </div>
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`JSX` collapses whitespaces, in this case you can use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html) like so

```
var Component = React.createClass({
  content() {
    const text = `
      keep formatting

      keep spaces
   `;

    return { __html: text };
  },

  render: function() {
    return <div 
      style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap' }} 
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ this.content() } 
    />
  }
});
```

**Note:** For new versions of React/JSX, there is no need to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

```js
const App = () => (
  <div style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap' }}>
    {`
      keep formatting

      keep spaces


      keep spaces
   `}
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This no longer seems to be the case. I was able to just add the CSS property and it worked. No need for `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

Comment: @inostiam Thanks, added the note.

Comment: +100 Mind blown... This answer deserves way more credit than what its currently getting..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` but this is, well, dangerous. :) What else you can do, which is what we do in our app, is convert the string to React elements, for example to render line-breaks:

```
text.split("\n").map((text, i) => i ? [<br/>, text] : text)
```

You can make this into a function or a component like `<MultilineText text={text}/>`.

[Example on CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqGeNm).

In our case we also tried using `whiteSpace` and found that none of the options quite gave us what we wanted.