# Split String in Javascript but keep delimiter /

Tags: javascript, split

```
var string = 'Animation/rawr/javascript.js'

//expected output 
// ['Animation/', 'rawr/', 'javascript.js']
```

I'm having trouble splitting this string properly.  Can I get some help on this?

string.split(/(/)/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS string.split() without removing the delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514144/js-string-split-without-removing-the-delimiters)

Answer (score 9):

You can do it with a regular expression using [`''.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) instead of `split`:

```
var str = 'Animation/rawr/javascript.js';
var tokens = str.match(/[^\/]+\/?|\//g);
```

The first part `[^\/]+\/?` matches as many non forward slashes it can optionally followed by a `/`.
The second part `\/` (after the or: `|`) matches a lone forward slash.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to `split` it,
you have to add the `"/"`
afterwards.
But the more efficient way would be a **regex**.

**Split and add "/" afterwards:**

```js
var string = 'Animation/rawr/javascript.js';
var arr = string.split("/");

arr.forEach(function(e, i, a) {
  a[--i] += "/";
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(arr));
```