# How to join two half in RxJs

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have a stream like this

```
---ab---ab---a---ba---bab---ab---ab---ab--->
```

And I want this.

```
---ab---ab------ab----ab-ab-ab---ab---ab--->
```

The point is, that I have data with beginning and end (JSON) and sometimes the data is cut in the half in the stream, and I want to join them again. How can I do that?

Comment: How do you distinguish `ab` and `a` though? I was thinking about [bufferCount](http://rxmarbles.com/#bufferCount) but that is not the right thing, I'm sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved:

```
import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {last} from 'lodash';

const data$ = Rx.Observable.of('ab','ab','a','ba','bab','aba','b','ab');
const line$ = data$.flatMap(data => {
    const lines = data.match(/[^b]+b?|b/g); // https://stackoverflow.com/a/36465144/598280 https://stackoverflow.com/a/25221523/598280
    return Rx.Observable.from(lines);
});

const isComplete$ = line$.scan((acc, value) => {
    const isLineEndingLast = last(acc.value) === 'b';
    const id = isLineEndingLast ? acc.id + 1 : acc.id;
    const complete = last(value) === 'b';
    return {value, id, complete};
}, {value: 'b', id: 0, complete: true});

const grouped$ = isComplete$
    .groupBy(data => data.id, data => data, group => group.first(data => data.complete))
    .flatMap(group => group.reduce((acc, data) => acc + data.value, ''));

grouped$.subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a job for the scan operator

```
// substitute appropriate real-world logic
const isProperlyFormed = (x) => x === 'ab'  
const isIncomplete = (x) => x[0] === 'a' && x.length === 1
const startsWithEnding = (x) => x[0] === 'b'
const getCorrected = (buffer, x) => buffer.prev + x[0]
const getTail = (buffer, x) => x.slice(1)

const initialBuffer = {
  emit: [],
  prev: null
}

const result = source
  .scan((buffer, x) => {
    if (isProperlyFormed(x)) {
      buffer = {emit: [x], prev:null}
    }
    if (isIncomplete(x)) {
      buffer = {emit: [], prev:x}
    }
    if (startsWithEnding(x)) {
      const corrected = getCorrected(buffer, x)
      const tail = getTail(buffer, x)
      if (isProperlyFormed(tail)) {
        buffer = {emit: [corrected, tail], prev: null}
      } else {
        buffer = {emit: [corrected], prev: tail}
      }
    }
    return buffer
  }, initialBuffer)
  .flatMap(x => x.emit)
```

Working [CodePen](https://codepen.io/RMatsen/pen/QqZQXL)

***Edit***

Looking at the test input stream, I think a case is missing, which will break the above.

I changed the test from

```
---ab---ab---a---ba---bab---ab---ab---ab--->
```

to

```
---ab---ab---a---ba---bab---aba---b---ab--->
```

and also slimmed down the algorithm

```
const getNextBuffer = (x) => {
  const items = x.split(/(ab)/g).filter(y => y)  // get valid items plus tail
  return {
    emit: items.filter(x => x === 'ab'),    // emit valid items
    save: items.filter(x => x !== 'ab')[0]  // save tail
  }
}

const initialBuffer = {
  emit: [],
  save: null
}

const result = source
  .scan((buffer, item) => {
    const bufferAndItem = (buffer.save ? buffer.save : '') + item
    return getNextBuffer(bufferAndItem)
  }, initialBuffer)
  .flatMap(x => x.emit)
```

Working example [CodePen](https://codepen.io/RMatsen/pen/bomKWx)

Answer (score 1):

First split the stream into full responses and partial. Then check if response is full. Full responses are good as such. Partial responses need to be synchronized, so we split their stream into first and second halves and just zip those streams together.

The strange looking `Rx.Observable.of(g.partition(x => x[0] === 'a'))` is because `partition` operator returns pair of observables, which cannot be chained.

```js
const testStream = Rx.Observable.of('a1', 'a2', '_ab', 'b1', 'a3', 'b2', '_ab', 'a4', 'b3', '_ab', 'b4', 'a5', 'b5', '_ab')

testStream
  .groupBy(x => (x[0] === '_' && 'full') || 'partial')
  .mergeMap(g =>
    Rx.Observable.if(
      () => g.key == 'full',
      g,
      Rx.Observable.of(g.partition(x => x[0] === 'a'))
        .mergeMap(([as, bs]) => Rx.Observable.zip(as, bs))
    )
  )
  .do(x => console.log(x))
  .subscribe()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.4.3/Rx.min.js"></script>
```