# How can I split a string without losing the separator and without regex?

Tags: javascript

I have a string similar to `"<p></p>"`. Now, I want to split this string, so I have 2 tags. If I do

`var arr = "<p></p>".split("><")` , I get an array that looks like

`["<p", "/p>"]`

Is there a simple way to keep the separator in this split? NOT a REGEX (Not a dupe) I want :

```
["<p>","</p>"]
```

Comment: What if there is some content between them? Maybe you need `<.*?>`

Comment: presume there will not be. I am just curious about keeping the separator within the string for now.

Comment: @jmcgui05 see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001953/javascript-and-regex-split-string-and-keep-the-separator

Comment: If you want to grap something like HTML tags from JavaScript, I suggest to use RegExp.

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for the google link. How many of those solutions are Regex? My question was if there was a way to do this on a split. I did not ask for a regex. Your profile says you like to help people, many thanks for that.

Comment: @modernator—regular expressions are not a good tool for parsing HTML, see [*this answer*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: The link was intended as a help. You cannot keep the delimiter in split without a regex or a subsequent processing of the array as seen in the answer below.

Comment: [Here is a cool hack from the google search](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4514241/295783) `var string = '<p></p>asdoasidhaois<p></p>adaosdja<p></p>'
var delim='><',parts= string.split(delim);
for (var i= parts.length; i-->1;)
    parts.splice(i, 0, delim);
console.log(parts)`

Comment: @mplungjan "You cannot keep the delimiter without regex or processing the array". Why not just say that, which would answer the question instead of incorrectly closing out as a duplicate of questions with regex solutions? It seems I have to explicitly state that I want to know a) if some is possible, and b) how to code it myself without help from regex or some library. Thats the whole point of SO, is to learn.

Comment: Ok ok... Reopened...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since javascript regex doesn't support look behind assertion it's not possible with [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method. Use [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method to get the complete string.

```js
var arr = "<p></p>".match(/[\s\S]+?>(?=<|$)/g)

console.log(arr)
```

---

Without regex and using split you can do something like this.

```js
var arr = "<p></p>".split('><').map(function(v, i, arr1) {
  if (i != 0)
    v = '<' + v;
  if (i < arr1.length - 1)
    v += '>';
  return v;
})

// using ternary 
var arr1 = "<p></p>".split('><').map(function(v, i, arr1) {
  return (i != 0 ? '<' : '') + v + (i < arr1.length - 1 ? '>' : '');
})

console.log(arr);
console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this without a regular expression, you'll need some kind of parser. Inspect every character, build up chunks and store them in an array. You may then want to process the bits, looking for tokens or doing other processing. E.g.

```js
/* Break string into chunks of <...>, </...> and anything in between.
** @param {string} s - string to parse
** @returns {Array} chunks of string
*/
function getChunks(s) {
    var parsed = [];
    var limit = s.length - 1;

    s.split('').reduce(function(buffer, char, i) {
      var startTag = char == '<';
      var endTag   = char == '/';
      var closeTag = char == '>';

      if (startTag) {
        if (buffer.length) {
          parsed.push(buffer);
        }
        buffer = char;

      } else if (endTag) {
        buffer += char;

      } else if (closeTag) {
        parsed.push(buffer + char)
        buffer = '';

      } else {
        buffer += char;
      }

      if (i == limit && buffer.length) {
        parsed.push(buffer);
      }

      return buffer;
    }, '');
    return parsed;
}


['<p></p>',
 '<div>More complex</div>',
 '<span>broken tag</sp'
].forEach(function(s){
  console.log(s + ' => [' + getChunks(s) + ']')
});
```

Note that this is very simple and just looks for `<...>` and `</...>` where `...` can be anything.