# How to split an array after a specified regex pattern in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I would like to split a string of text into an array of sentences without loosing the punctuation mark.

```
var string = 'This is the first sentence. This is another sentence! This is a question?' 
var splitString = string.split(/[!?.] /);
splitString  
  => ["This is the first sentence", "This is another sentence", "This is a question?"]
```

Only the last punctuation mark(?) is kept. What is the best way to split after the punctuation marks on all the sentences so that splitString returns the following instead?

```
["This is the first sentence.", "This is another sentence!", "This is a question?"]
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001953/javascript-and-regex-split-string-and-keep-the-separator

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514144/js-string-split-without-removing-the-delimiters

Comment: Anyways, it's easily googleable by "`javascript string split keep delimiter`"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `split` to target where you want to break your text, you can use [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with a global regular expression and target the text you want to keep:

```
var splitString = string.match(/\S.+?[!?.]/g)
```

This avoids the need to use look-behinds, which are unsupported in JavaScript's regex flavor as of now, or additional calls to methods like `Array#filter`:

```js
var string = 'This is the first sentence. This is another sentence! Is this a question?'

var splitString = string.match(/\S.+?[!?.]/g)

console.log(splitString)
```

Answer (score 1):

***Few approaches:***

The solution using `String.prototype.match()` function to get an array of sentences:

```js
var string = 'This is the first sentence. This is another sentence! This is a question?',
    items = string.match(/\S[^.!?]+[.?!]/g);

console.log(items);
```

The alternative solution using `String.prototype.split()` function would look like below:

```js
var string = 'This is the first sentence. This is another sentence! This is a question?',
    items = string.split(/(\S[^.!?]+[.?!])/g).filter(function(s){ return s.trim(); });

console.log(items);
```

`\S[^.!?]+` - will match all characters except specified punctuation chars   `[^.!?]` and starting with non-whitespace character `\S`

Comment: Note that this also matches a leading space at the beginning of some sentences.

Comment: @gyre, can't agree with you

Comment: I see you edited your answer so this is no longer an issue. It was such a small window I did not get a chance to see the changes before commenting :)

Comment: @gyre, yes, I've made the edit right before your comment