# JS / TS splitting string by a delimiter without removing the delimiter

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a string that I need to split by a certain delimiter and convert into an array, but without removing the delimiter itself.
For example, consider the following code:

```
var str = "#mavic#phantom#spark";
str.split("#") //["", "mavic", "phantom", "spark"]
```

I need the output to be as follows:

```
["#mavic", "#phantom", "#spark"]
```

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514144/js-string-split-without-removing-the-delimiters) but that does not answer my question.

Comment: You're not splitting (IMO), instead you're matching `/#[^#]+/g`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) by positive lookahead of `#`.

```js
var string = "#mavic#phantom#spark",
    splitted = string.split(/(?=#)/);

console.log(splitted);
```

Comment: Regular expressions are awesome.  I like using [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/TAkEk0/1) to test them out (still learning!)

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what I needed, interestingly never heard of "positive lookahead". Many thanks.

Comment: Important point here is that the separator can be either a string or regular expression. [String.prototype.split() MDN doc for reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#Parameters)

Answer (score 1):

Split the string by `#` and use the `reduce` to return the modified string

```js
var str = "#mavic#phantom#spark";
let x = str.split("#").reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (curr !== '') {
    acc.push('#' + curr);
  }
  return acc;
}, [])
console.log(x)
```

Comment: `map` would be easier.

Comment: @NinaScholz initially i thought of map but element at 0th index is undefined http://jsfiddle.net/m9e0c48L/

Comment: `slice(1).map(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is also some non-regexp methods of solving your task:

**Solution 1** classical approach - iterate over the string and each time when we find `indexOf` our delimiter, we push to the result array the substring between current position and the next position. In the else block we have a case for the last substring - we simply add it to the result array and break the loop.

```
const delimiter = '#';
const result1 = [];
let i = 0;
while (i < str.length) {
  const nextPosition = str.indexOf(delimiter, i+1);
  if (nextPosition > 0) {
    result1.push(str.substring(i, nextPosition));
    i = nextPosition;
  } else {
    result1.push(str.substring(i));
    break;
  }
}
```

**Solution 2** - split the initial string starting at index 1 (in order to not include empty string in the result array) and then just map the result array by concatenating the delimiter and current array item.

```
const result2 = str.substr(1).split(delimiter).map(s => delimiter + s);
```

Answer (score 0):

another way:
filter empty elements after splitting, and map these elements to start with the character you splitted with.

```
string.split("#").filter((elem) => elem).map((elem) => "#" + elem);
```