# Split a string into a list of strings

Tags: javascript, string, replace, split, substring

I have an input Json string like this:

```
var x= "[{\"name\":\"ahmed\",\"age\":\"26\"}, 
{\"name\":\"Sam\",\"age\":\"25\"}]"
```

I want to split it to a list of strings from{ to } as follows without removing a delimiter

```
var list;
 list[0]= {\"name\":\"ahmed\",\"age\":\"26\"}
 list[1]= {\"name\":\"Sam\",\"age\":\"25\"}
```

using the split method removes the delimiter and does not yield the correct format

```
x= x.replace(/\[\/]/g, '/'); //to remove [ and ]
x= x.replace(  /},/ ,'}\n' ); // does not split the string to list of strings
list = x; // type mismatch error since x is a string and list is array
```

Comment: How about parsing the JSON using JSON.parse?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS string.split() without removing the delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514144/js-string-split-without-removing-the-delimiters)

Comment: @Teemu thanks alot.. don't know how this didn't cross my mind...

Answer (score 1):

As commented above by Teemu, using `JSON.parse` is the safe and correct way to parse json.

```js
const x = "[{\"name\":\"ahmed\",\"age\":\"26\"},{\"name\":\"Sam\",\"age\":\"25\"}]";

console.log(JSON.parse(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse it to JSON first then use `map` to make list out of it.

```
var parsedX = JSON.parse(x);
var list = parsedX.map(x => JSON.stringify(x).replace(/"/g,'\\"'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use following code to achieve desired result with this particular type of json:

```
var str = "[{\"name\":\"ahmed\",\"age\":\"26\"}, {\"name\":\"Sam\",\"age\":\"25\"}]";
var list = str.match(/[{][^{}]*[}]/gm);

alert(list)
```

Fell free to ask if you have any questions: